# Silverlight: Applying datacontext to an element within a style

Tags: silverlight, datacontext, styles

I have defined a style in `app.xaml`. This style contains several text TextBlocks which I would like to controle as I apply the style to an object, in this case a UserPin.
How can I access these TextBlocks runtime?
I get the style by:

```
Style = Application.Current.Resources["UserPin"] as Style;
```

The style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Name="UserPin" TargetType="RRML_UserControls:UserPin" >
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5" />
    <Setter Property="AnchorPoint" Value="0.5,0.5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RRML_UserControls:UserPin">
                <Grid Height="71.969" Width="Auto">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="PART_PinScale" />
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="29"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.247*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.753*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Height="Auto" Source="Resources/Users.png" x:Name="PART_imgUser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" x:Name="txtBottom" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LocationName}">
                        <TextBlock.DataContext>
                            <RRML_RRMLServiceReference:Location LocationName="Initial Name"/>
                        </TextBlock.DataContext>
                    </TextBlock>                            
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="L" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="R" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                            
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `TextBlock` value I'm trying to set is `txtBottom`.
As you can see I have tried to apply a datacontext and a databinding to the field. This works, but all objects get the value "Initial Name" of course.

My questions are:

1. how can I apply my datacontext so `txtBottom.Text` changes, or
2. how can I change the value of the `TextBlock` named `txtBottom` without databinding?
3. in short can I access these fields or properties at all?

Runtime :)
So far I have found that Triggers may be used only in WPF.

I think of something like this:

```
var styledobject = new NiceObject();
styledobject.Style = Application.Current.Resources["UserPin"] as Style;
styledobject.DataContext = locationData;
```

Where `locationData` is my object containing data.

If anyone wonders; I am placing icons on a map and want to name them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not explicitly apply `DataContext` on the `TextBlock`. `DataContext` is inherited by child `FrameworkElements`. You should try to set data context explicitly as little and as high up the Visual Tree as possible (for your own sanity's sake :-))
2. If this is a custom control, you can override on the `OnApplyTemplate` method and use the `GetTemplateChild(string name)` to retrieve references to named elements within your control.

   ```
   public override void OnApplyTemplate() 
   {
           base.OnApplyTemplate();

   TextBlock txtBottom = GetTemplateChild("txtBottom") as TextBlock;
   }
   ```
3. Externally, if you must, you can imperatively access that specific control at runtime using an extension method to traverse the Visual Tree to find it by name.

   ```
   public static T FindChild<T>(this DependencyObject element, string name)
               where T : FrameworkElement
   {
   //Code to find the control
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Alternative 2 solved the problem. I found that the key here is OnApplyTemplate due to what I found under Remarks in Help:
"Call GetTemplateChild in order to return references to objects that come from the template after it is instantiated."

/Øyvind